# How to Broadcast Live USTREAM in Flowplayer with RTMP Plugin?

Tags: video-streaming, rtmp, flowplayer

I have a live stream being broadcast with USTREAM. I am able to find the RTMP URL and stream key under my USTREAM dashboard's channel remote settings.

I would like to stream my channel live through Flowplayer. I have downloaded the RTMP plugin and have set the netConnectionUrl to the USTREAM RTMP URL and the clip URL to the Stream key, but it is not working.

It gives the following error:

```
201, Unable to load stream or clip file, connection failed, clip: '[Clip] 'XSWjEqbQbMPS8BdcEUsqJZJgUvgNydFu''
```

Here is my JavaScript settings for Flowplayer:

```
flowplayer("player", "/js/vendor/flowplayer/flash/flowplayer-3.2.16.swf", {
  clip: {
    url: "XSWjEqbQbMPS8BdcEUsqJZJgUvgNydFu", // Stream Key
    live: true,
    autoPlay: false,
    autoBuffering: true,
    provider: 'rtmp'
  },
  plugins: {
    audio: {
      url: '/js/vendor/flowplayer/flash/flowplayer.audio-3.2.10.swf'
    },
    rtmp: {
      url: '/js/vendor/flowplayer/flash/flowplayer.rtmp-3.2.12.swf',
      netConnectionUrl: 'rtmp://1.3048370.fme.ustream.tv/ustreamVideo/3048370' // RTMP Url
    }
  }
});
```

Does anybody know how to get USTREAM working through Flowplayer?